# Как распарсить нетривиальный XML на питоне?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

```
<robot generated="20150623 14:50:18.176" generator="Robot 2.8.7 (Python 2.6.6 on linux2)">
    <suite source="/home/Robot" id="s1" name="Robot">
        <suite source="/home/Join273_helo_resp_2_1_trace0001_L.txt" id="s1-s1" name="g helo wiL">
            <test id="s1-s1-t1" name="g_helo_with_C_OrJoin273_helo_resp_2_1_trace0001_L">
                <kw type="kw" name="SmtpLibrary.Connect To Smtp">
                    <doc></doc>
                    <arguments>
                        <arg>${host}</arg>
                        <arg>${port}</arg>
                    </arguments>
                    <status status="PASS" endtime="20150623 14:50:18.241" starttime="20150623 14:50:18.234"></status>
                </kw>
                <kw type="kw" name="SmtpLibrary.Check Response">
                    <doc></doc>
                    <arguments>
                        <arg>220</arg>
                    </arguments>
                    <msg timestamp="14:50:18.257" level="INFO">220 localhost SMTP Server (JAMES SMTP Server 2.3.2)(MSK)</msg>
                    <status status="PASS" endtime="20150623 14:50:18.257" starttime="20150623 14:50:18.241"></status>
                </kw>
                <kw type="kw" name="SmtpLibrary.Helo">
                    <doc></doc>
                    <arguments>
                        <arg>name</arg>
                    </arguments>
                    <status status="PASS" endtime="20150623 14:50:18.258" starttime="20150623 14:50:18.257"></status>
                </kw>
                <kw type="kw" name="SmtpLibrary.Check Response">
                    <doc></doc>
                    <arguments>
                        <arg>250</arg>
                    </arguments>
                    <msg timestamp="20150623 14:50:18.259" level="INFO">250 localhost Hello name (localhost [127.0.0.1])</msg>
                    <status status="PASS" endtime="20150623 14:50:18.259" starttime="20150623 14:50:18.259"></status>
            </test>
            <doc>Test "g_helo_with_C_OrJoin273_" in keyword-driven format.</doc>
            <metadata></metadata>
            <status status="PASS" endtime="20150623 14:50:18.263" starttime="20150623 14:50:18.224"></status>
        </suite>
        <suite source="/home/_2_2_trace0001_L.txt" id="s1-s2" name="OrJoin273 helo resp 2 2 trace0001 L">
            <test id="s1-s2-t1" name="g_helo_with_C_OrJoin273_helo_resp_2_2_trace0001_L">
                <kw type="kw" name="SmtpLibrary.Connect To Smtp">
                    <doc></doc>
                    <arguments>
                        <arg>${host}</arg>
                        <arg>${port}</arg>
                    </arguments>
                    <status status="PASS" endtime="20150623 14:50:18.275" starttime="20150623 14:50:18.274"></status>
                </kw>
                <kw type="kw" name="SmtpLibrary.Check Response">
                    <doc></doc>
                    <arguments>
                        <arg>220</arg>
                    </arguments>
                    <msg timestamp="201506" level="INFO">220 localhost SMTP Server (JAMES SMTP Server 2.3.2) 14:50:18 +0400 (MSK)</msg>
                    <status status="PASS" endtime="14:50:18.277" starttime="20150623 14:50:18.275"></status>
                </kw>
                <kw type="kw" name="SmtpLibrary.Helo">
                    <doc></doc>
                    <arguments>
                        <arg>name</arg>
                    </arguments>
                    <status status="PASS" endtime="20150623 14:50:18.277" starttime="20150623 14:50:18.277"></status>
                </kw>
                <kw type="kw" name="SmtpLibrary.Check Response">
                    <doc></doc>
                    <arguments>
                        <arg>255</arg>
                    </arguments>
                    <msg timestamp="20150623 14:50:18.278" level="INFO">250 localhost Hello name (localhost [127.0.0.1])</msg>
                    <status status="FAIL" endtime="20150623 14:50:18.278" starttime="20150623 14:50:18.278"></status>
                </kw>
            </test>
            <doc>Test "g_helo_with_C_OrJoin273_helo_resp_2_2_trace0001_L" in keyword-driven format.</doc>
            <metadata></metadata>
            <status status="FAIL" endtime="20150623 14:50:18.284" starttime="20150623 14:50:18.266"></status>
        </suite>
    </suite>
    <errors></errors>
</robot>
```

Как распарсить так, чтоб в выводе было: `suite source` и соответствующие ему `kw name`, `arguments`, `status`?
Проблема в том, что я не знаю как выводить список `suite source`, а в нем еще список `kw name`, `arguments`, `status`.

Comment: не вижу ничего нетривиального. По умолчанию для работы с xml можно использовать [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: я не думал, что в тривиальных примерах есть рекурсия.
Впервые столкнулся с разбором xml, казалось проще

Comment: рекурсивный код является естественным для древовидной структуры xml, но можно и без явной рекурсии как в [моём ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432256/23044).

Comment: @Falko94 _python_ уже есть в метках вопроса - не нужно добавлять эти слова в заголовок вопроса. Полный заголовок сейчас выглядит как _python - Как распарсить нетривиальный XML на питоне?_, и это неправильно.

Comment: @Regent: `python` и `питон` разные слова для некоторых поисковиков.  Небольшая избыточность не убъёт, но в крайности не нужно впадать.

Comment: @jfs да какие уж тут крайности... Если кто-то в поиске набирает _питон парсинг иксемель_, то это уже, пардон, к этому человеку вопросы. Можно ещё вопрос назвать _Как распарсить XML сидя на анаконде?_

Comment: `> я не думал, что в тривиальных примерах есть рекурсия. Впервые столкнулся с разбором xml, казалось проще`
Попробуйте haskell =)

Comment: Я не знаток Python'a да и  Xml разбираю впервые, поэтому не нужно много умничать.
Советы учту, в следующий раз буду формулировать вопрос корректнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам поможет `minidom`:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

om = minidom.parseString(x)
root = om.getElementsByTagName('robot')[0]

# Далее что-то, к примеру:

def walk(x, d=0):
    print('    ' * d + str(x))
    if x.attributes is not None:
        for i, j in x.attributes.items():
            print('    ' * d + '  | ' + i + ': ' + j)
    for i in x.childNodes:
        walk(i, d+1)

walk(root)
```

Comment: спасибоо))как боженька понял меня и то, что надо скинул)

Answer (score 2):

Для сравнения, код на основе [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

robot = etree.parse('input.xml').getroot()
for suite in robot.iter('suite'):
    print("suite " + suite.get('source'))
    for kw in suite.findall('./test/kw'):
        print("\tkw" + kw.get('name'))
        for arg in kw.find('arguments') or []:
            print("\t\targ " + arg.text)
        print("\t\t" +
              "\n\t\t".join(map("=".join, sorted(kw.find('status').items()))))
```

#### Output

```
suite /home/Robot
suite /home/Join273_helo_resp_2_1_trace0001_L.txt
    kwSmtpLibrary.Connect To Smtp
        arg ${host}
        arg ${port}
        endtime=20150623 14:50:18.241
        starttime=20150623 14:50:18.234
        status=PASS
    kwSmtpLibrary.Check Response
        arg 220
        endtime=20150623 14:50:18.257
        starttime=20150623 14:50:18.241
        status=PASS
...
suite /home/_2_2_trace0001_L.txt
    kwSmtpLibrary.Connect To Smtp
        arg ${host}
        arg ${port}
        endtime=20150623 14:50:18.275
        starttime=20150623 14:50:18.274
        status=PASS
    kwSmtpLibrary.Check Response
        arg 220
        endtime=14:50:18.277
        starttime=20150623 14:50:18.275
        status=PASS
...
```